# How to integrate the techprocess payment gateway in android application

Tags: android, payment-gateway

how to integrate a techprocess payment gateway in android they have given me some jar files.
Any help would be apprieciated
Thanksin advance

Comment: have you integrated techprocess payment gateway in Android application?  Did you find any compatible jar file ?  Can you please share the details.

Comment: @KumaravelSelvaraj tech-process gonna give complete document to integrate it with you application.By the way they don't provide  SDk like PayPal u have hit the soap URL and open the pages in web view.